# Registering an already instantiated class in MVVMLight's SimpleIoc

Tags: silverlight, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, mvvm-light

I'm moving to using the SimpleIoc for Dependency Injection from using a Static class. There is a `Register<TClass>(Func<TClass> factory) where TClass : class` method in the SimpleIoc, but I can't find any examples of using it. Here's a link [to the source code](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/24f5a515554b#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras%20%28NET35%29/Ioc/SimpleIoc.cs).

Am I approaching this correctly, or does DI always need to create it at register time? Is this the method I should use to register the class? <strike>Can you give me an example on how to do this?</strike>

This is the Silverlight code I'm trying to update.
EDIT: moved my approach to an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved my example from my question to an answer, since no one else has answered it in 22 days. EDIT: this is better.

```
   public partial class App : Application
   {               
            /// <summary>
            /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="App"/> class.
            /// </summary>
            public App()
            {
              this.Startup += (s, e) =>
              {
                // create and register it now
                SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IUserToken>(() => { return new UserToken(); });
                 SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<IUserToken>().PopulateUserTokenFromService(() =>
                {
                  // don't do anything until the user token is populated from the server
                  InitializeComponent();                 

                  this.RootVisual = new View();
                });
              }
            }
```